# cascading combo boxes and queries in access

Tags: microsoft-access, sql

I am using access. I have queried a table using a form to trigger the query, with three combo boxes(cascading) the results how ever are not based on the three criteria, only the first. The code below was written to allow the cascading boxes.
However I would like the results for location = the respective combo box and cant find the way to insert the code, all methods tried resulted in a failed cascading combo box.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OFFERING.Lecture, OFFERING.Course_no, OFFERING.Location,OFFERING.Start_date
FROM OFFERING, COURSE WHERE OFFERING.Course_no=[forms]![Form1]![Combo0];
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I'm unclear as to whether this is the SQL for the query for your table or the row source for one of your cascading comboboxes.  If this is for your cascading comboboxes, then you might just need to refresh your form so that the combo box can get the updated list.

I did notice that in the FROM statement, you have two tables listed (Offering and Course) but no JOIN.  Not sure if this is a typo or not as it isn't very common to do this, but not impossible.

I would also check the Bound To property of your combo box to see which field from its row source is being used as the value for the combo box.  It is not uncommon to have the combo box hide the first column and display the second column so you might not be comparing the correct values to the field in your table.